# C# LINQ get count to dictionary

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, dictionary, counter

I got a LINQ query with [Entity Framework](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity_Framework) (EF) and getting a list of items. Now I want to create a dictionary with the  incrementing index of the item and the item itself.

I have it like this:

```
result = context
    .Items
    .Where(b => !b.Deleted)
    .OrderBy(b => b.Name)
    .ToDictionary(COUNTHERE, b => b.Name)
```

So the dictionary have to look like this:

```
1: "item1"
2: "item2"
3: "item5"
4: "item10"
5: "item100"
```

Comment: You need to inverse the key-value. Think what would happen if `item1` and `item5` were to occur 3 times.

Comment: The itemnames are unique in the database

Comment: What? If the items are unique, then why on earth do you need to count them? The count is always going to be 1...

Comment: @AndreasFurster the KEYS should be unique, while the itemnames are the VALUES. One way to solve this problem if you do want to be able to search by count, is to use Lookup instead of Dictionary: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.tolookup%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Comment: I think he means an incrementing index, not a count.

Comment: @PeterHansen, even so, the key needs to be unique. That was my impression to, after his response. All the other comments still stand.

Comment: @AndreiV If the key is just a autoincrementing int, it will be unique I guess. I don't know really. The question is a bit confusing.

Comment: Sorry, as @Peter Hansen mentioned, i meant the incrementing index.

Comment: @AndreasFurster, from where does this _incrementing index_ come from? Is it an auto generated field from the data table (like a *primary key*)? Is it meant to be something that you compute/modify trough code?

Comment: It isn't in the database. I just have a list of items and want to put them in a dictionary with as key an incrementing index.

Comment: @AndreasFurster, this means that you want to generate yourself the index, when you add the data to your dictionary?

Comment: @AndreiV, I think so, yes.

Comment: Based on the accepted answer, why even have a `Dictionary`? it would just hold the index for the elements of a regular `List`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use:

```
int count = 0;
var result = context
    .Items
    .Where(b => !b.Deleted)
    .OrderBy(b => b.Name)
    .ToDictionary(b => ++count, b => b.Name);
```

Comment: +1, new knowledge, that it works fine passing local variable in ToDictionary

Answer (score 7):

I think what you need is to have the item name as the key instead the count as the key, because if there is two items that have the same count, it will throw exception that the key has been added.

Then you can Use `GroupBy` before `ToDictionary` so that you can count it.

```
result = context
    .Items
    .Where(b => !b.Deleted)
    .GroupBy(x => x.Name)
    .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.Count())
    .OrderBy(g => g.Key);
```

based on your updated comment, then what you need is

```
result = context
    .Items
    .Where(b => !b.Deleted)
    .OrderBy(b => b.Name)
    .AsEnumerable()
    .Select((v,i) => new { i, v.Name })
    .ToDictionary(g => g.i + 1, g => g.Name);
```

Note that you need to add `AsEnumerable` so that the `Select` clause works as linq to object (`Select` that accept index is not supported in L2S).

Comment: Thanks! This is is what i want it to be. Also thanks for the note :)

Comment: the first `result = context...` - `GroupBy` will order by Name and Name is unique, so the `g.Count()` will always be 1. Or maybe I am missing something..? :-.

Comment: @Default, you're right the first part should be 1, if it was meant to be, anyway, it's obsolete, thanks

Answer (score 0):

An alternative way of achieving this is:

```
var sortedNames = context
    .Items
    .Where(b => !b.Deleted)
    .Select(b => b.Name)
    .OrderBy(b => b.Name)
    .ToArray();

result = Enumerable.Range(1, sortedNames.Length)
    .ToDictionary(i => i, i => sortedNames[i - 1]);
```

To get zero-based numbering, use `Enumerable.Range(0, sortedNames.Length)` and `sortedNames[i]` instead.